# Reload aiohttp SSL Certificates

Tags: python, ssl, aiohttp

I'm running a SSL secured HTTP server based on [aiohttp's high-level interface](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v0.14.0/web_reference.html#module-aiohttp.web). I'm running the server as follows:

```
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=ssl_certfile, keyfile=ssl_keyfile)
aiohttp.web.run_app(app, ssl_context=ssl_context)
```

When the SSL certificate is renewed the server does not pick up the renewed server certificate but keeps serving the old certificate.

I don't seem to be able to find any documentation regarding renewal of SSL certs at runtime. How can I replace the server's SSL certificate at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you attempted to just reload a new cert chain into the `ssl_context` you create when you need to, e.g. with a timed repeating task that checks whether the certfile and keyfile have been changed since they were last loaded?

Based on a peek into the internals...

- [`aiohttp.web.run_app`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/e74d40cffd1cb352639466e6e3cd830abd99d442/aiohttp/web.py#L324) passes the `ssl_context` down ...
- to [`BaseSite`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/e74d40cffd1cb352639466e6e3cd830abd99d442/aiohttp/web_runner.py#L53)s, which use them when ...
- [calling `asyncio.create_server`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_server)...
- ... and then there's a whole lot more abstraction and my eyes are starting to glaze over...

... but based on that cursory look I don't think the context ever gets copied in a way that would make that not work.

Failing that, I think you'd have a better time simply restarting the server upon SSL certificate renewal.

Comment: I added a background thread that invokes `ssl_context.load_cert_chain()` every couple of minutes. That seems to do the trick!